# LaunchScreen.storyboard shows on iPhone but not on iPad?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I am using a LaunchScreen.storyboard to drive the launch screen in my iOS app. It works fine when I run the app on my iPhone. The problem is when I try to run the app on the iPad the launch screen is black.

I am not sure how to fix this problem.

I have created the LaunchScreen.storyboard using the built in option:

[image]

I then went to the target settings and made sure to select it:

[image]

Any idea as to why when run on the iPad I could be getting a black screen?

This is what I see in the info.plist:
[image]

Comment: Look in your Info.plist. Is there a separate entry for an iPad specific launch screen? If so, remove that entry.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the only launch screen setting entry I see in the info.plist

Comment: Did you ever sort this out? I'm having the same problem. Even worse, it works perfectly on iPhone devices and iPad sim, but iPad device - black launch screen.